# Is there a way to avoid Type MisMatch Error in EXCEL VBA when iterating through an Array?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have the following code throwing a Type MisMatch Error on the line highlighted below. The code is supposed to simply identify empty elements in the input array (stat5) and replace them with a single period in the output array (ArrayOut). However, when it encounters the empty element in position (9,2) of stat5, it throws the Type MisMatch error:

[image]

From what I have read about the Type MisMatch error, it sounds like data assigned to a variable does not match the type of the variable. However, in my case, I am encountering the error EVEN when I attempt to simply call the value of stat5(9,1) in the Debug.Print statement below. It hangs on the Print statement (which is not an assignment statement, so I can't figure out what is mismatching with what):

[image]

Here is the code:

```
ReDim ArrayOut(1 To X1N, 1 To 1)
For i2 = 1 To X1N
    If Len(Trim(stat5(i2, 2))) = 0 Then
        ArrayOut(i2, 1) = "."
    Else
        ArrayOut(i2, 1) = stat5(i2, 2)
    End If
Next i2
```

Here is the data in the input array (In this particular case, the non-missing values of the 2nd column of the array are constant, but this is not always the case). These are the values of stat5 when the error occurs in iteration 9 of the loop:

```
1   0.500285714
2   0.500285714
3   0.500285714
4   0.500285714
5   0.500285714
6   0.500285714
7   0.500285714
8   0.500285714
9   
10  0.500285714
```

## =========================================================

Here is the code that sets up stat5. All of this code runs without error:

```
    Dim stat1 As Variant
    Dim stat2 As Variant
    Dim stat3 As Variant
    Dim stat4 As Variant
    Dim stat5 As Variant

    'ReCombine Results for Final Printing
    'Add ObsNum to each
    'Prediction Set Results
    ReDim stat1(1 To X3N, 1 To 2)
    For i2 = 1 To X3N
        stat1(i2, 1) = X3(i2, 1)
        If Pred = True Then
            If NumberOfArrayDimensions(ArrayPredIn) = 1 Then
                stat1(i2, 2) = ArrayPredIn(i2)
            Else
                stat1(i2, 2) = ArrayPredIn(i2, 1)
            End If
        Else
            stat1(i2, 2) = ""
        End If
    Next i2
    'Estimation Set ResultS
    ReDim stat2(1 To UBound(X4, 1), 1 To 2)
    If NumberOfArrayDimensions(ArrayEstIn) = 1 Then
        For i2 = 1 To UBound(X5, 1)
            stat2(i2, 1) = X4(i2, 1)
            stat2(i2, 2) = ArrayEstIn(i2)
        Next i2
    Else
        For i2 = 1 To UBound(X5, 1)
            stat2(i2, 1) = X4(i2, 1)
            stat2(i2, 2) = ArrayEstIn(i2, 1)
        Next i2
    End If

    'Concatenate stat1, stat2, stat3
    ReDim stat5(1 To X1N, 1 To 2)
    stat5 = Combine(stat1, stat2)

    QuickSortArray stat5, , , 1
```

Here is the Combine function:

```
Function Combine(a As Variant, b As Variant, Optional stacked As Boolean = True) As Variant
    'assumes that A and B are 2-dimensional variant arrays
    'if stacked is true then A is placed on top of B
    'in this case the number of rows must be the same,
    'otherwise they are placed side by side A|B
    'in which case the number of columns are the same
    'LBound can be anything but is assumed to be
    'the same for A and B (in both dimensions)
    'False is returned if a clash

    Dim lb As Long, m_A As Long, n_A As Long
    Dim m_B As Long, n_B As Long
    Dim m As Long, N As Long
    Dim C As Variant

    If TypeName(a) = "Range" Then a = a.value
    If TypeName(b) = "Range" Then b = b.value

    lb = LBound(a, 1)
    m_A = UBound(a, 1)
    n_A = UBound(a, 2)
    m_B = UBound(b, 1)
    n_B = UBound(b, 2)

    If stacked Then
        m = m_A + m_B + 1 - lb
        N = n_A
        If n_B <> N Then
            Combine = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Else
        m = m_A
        If m_B <> m Then
            Combine = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        N = n_A + n_B + 1 - lb
    End If
    ReDim C(lb To m, lb To N)
    For i = lb To m
        For j = lb To N
            If stacked Then
                If i <= m_A Then
                    C(i, j) = a(i, j)
                Else
                    C(i, j) = b(lb + i - m_A - 1, j)
                End If
            Else
                If j <= n_A Then
                    C(i, j) = a(i, j)
                Else
                    C(i, j) = b(i, lb + j - n_A - 1)
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Combine = C
End Function
```

=========================================================================

UPDATE: When I check the type of each element of stat5, the type of element (9,2) is 8204 (while all the other (i2,2) elements are 5 = vbdouble). However, I'm not sure what this means: Has a multi-element array been saved to the (9,2) element of the array stat5? Is that possible?

[image]

I tried wrapping all of the calls to stat5(i2,2) with CStr(), hoping to convert the info in (9,2) to a string, but this also gives the same Type MisMatch error.

[image]

Locals window output:

[image]

===============================================================================

Results from the Locals window:

[image]

However, the variable type according to VarType() for elements (1-8,2) is vbDouble ("5") which seems to contradict the results in the Locals window:

[image]
[image]

===============================================================================

UPDATE: I was able to reproduce the error with stat1 BEFORE the Combine function was used to create stat5. Therefore, I do not believe that the problem is with the Combine function.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. How did you set up `stat5`?  How did you initially declare that variable?

Comment: I added some code that shows how stat5 is created, but it goes much further back than this.

Comment: I am learning that the elements of arrays in VBA can have differing types. If so, what is a quick and easy way to print the type of each element of an array as one loops through the elements?

Comment: Look at the `VarType` and `TypeName` functions.  The first is more comprehensive.

Comment: @Ron - Thanks. I have used VarType for variables and arrays before, but never for individual elements of a single array. I edited the original post with what I found.

Comment: 8204 means it's an array of variants. Hence the type mismatch. What do you see if you expand it in the locals window?

Comment: @Ron Element (9,2) of stat5 is an array of variants? I did not know that an element of an array could store another array. The Locals window seems to only provide info about stat5 (see output above in edited post). However, my problem is not with stat5 as a whole, but with only the element (9,2) in stat5.

Comment: Expand stat5 to see the individual elements

Comment: I suspect your issue is with your `Combine` function.

Comment: @Ron The expanded Locals window shows Variant (1 To 2). Is this analysis row-wise only? It does not seem to make the distinction between element (1,1) and element (1,2), for example. Nonetheless, the VarType() analysis shows different results. I am not sure why. See these results in the edited post above.

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to reproduce the error with stat1 BEFORE the Combine function was used to create stat5. Therefore, I do not believe that the problem is with the Combine function. See edited post above for image.

Comment: Someplace you will need to ensure that the array you are creating, and accessing, has the right sort of elements to avoid the type mismatch you are seeing.  Whether you do that in your `Combine` function, or elsewhere, is up to you.